# Is ERC-20 specific to Ethereum

Tags: erc-20

I have read a lot of informations about ERC20 tokens.

What i want to know is : Does it exists some ERC20 tokens which works with another blockchain than Ethereum ?

Or ERC20 is a specific Ethereum only technology ?

Thanks

Comment: This question is obviously not about Ethereum.

Comment: ERC20 is a standard, any Ethereum based blockchain can use that standard, other blockchain has similar standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ERC-20 is specific to Ethereum. Other blockchains have similar token standards that are copy-paste or inspired by ERC-20.

Comment: I would add that ERC-20 is not just "specific" to Ethereum - it was built on Ethereum in [November 2015](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/standards/tokens/erc-20/). Its very name is an acronym for "Ethereum Request for Comments 20".